# How to select name of the first child node of the current node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that contains various group items, some of which contains a "row" element within:

```
<foo id="2">
   <row>13/<row>
</foo>
<xxx id="3">
  <text>aaa</text>
</xxx>
<aaa id="4">
  <row>17</row>
</aaa>
```

Those that have nested `<row>` have to be transformed: the "row" should be wrapped into `<value>` and attributes copied from the "row" to the "value"

```
<foo> 
    <value id="4"> 
        <row>13</row> 
    </value> 
</foo>
```

In order to do it, I have to find whether my current element has a child called "row". Is there a generic way to do it in xslt? I tried `test="name(node()/*[1])='row'"` but it didn't select anything.
This is the xsl that uses test="row".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="row">
            <xsl:element name="attribute"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id">Sucess</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="attributeNone"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id">Failure</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: have you tried `test="row"`?

Comment: tried - doesn't work. I need to test the name of "my" first child

Comment: Huh? You said: `i have to find whether my current element has a child called "row"` That's exactly what my first comment does. Please update your question with the XSLT you're using that doesn't work. Also, is your desired output complete? The logic is not clear to me. Why is `<row>13</row>` in the output but `<row>17</row>` isn't?

Comment: Ok now that you've added your XSLT, it's making a tiny bit more sense. The reason `test="row"` doesn't work is because your context is the root (`/`). Also, you're trying to create elements that weren't mentioned anywhere in your original question. Please update your question with well formed input and the exact output you're trying to get. ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Oh, thanks, with `root` the `test="row"` worked! The sample tried to get this part working. Sorry for being unclear. I'll update the post further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given this input document ...**

```
<t>
  <foo id="2">
    <row>13</row>
  </foo>

  <xxx id="3">
    <text>aaa</text>
  </xxx>

  <aaa id="4">
    <row>17</row>
  </aaa>
</t>
```

**... this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...**

```
<xsl:transform
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="*[row]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*/@* except @id , * except row" />
    <value id="{@id}"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row" /> 
    </value> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**... will yield output ...**

```
<t>
   <foo>
      <value id="2">
         <row>13</row>
      </value>
   </foo>
   <xxx id="3">
      <text>aaa</text>
   </xxx>
   <aaa>
      <value id="4">
         <row>17</row>
      </value>
   </aaa>
</t>
```

Let me know if that is not what you wanted.

---

### Update 1:

Here is the XSLT 1.0 version ...

```
<xsl:transform
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="*[row]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[ local-name() != 'id']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[ not( self::row)]" />
    <value id="{@id}"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row" /> 
    </value> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! What exactly the `self ::` returns? The current node? Just trying to understand  the syntax.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in XSLT1?

Comment: self:: is the xpath axis of selection which selects the context node, if the context node is an element. I was being verbose, and it wasn't my best work. Instead of `self::*/@* except @id`, I could have just written `@* except @id` .

Comment: If your XSLT engine is the browser, you don't need to be constrained by XSLT 1.0, because you can use Saxon-CE. However, I will update and give you an XSLT 1.0 any way.